# How can I align only one item inside a css grid to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

```css
 div {
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
      width: 300px;
      background-color: lightyellow;
    }

    .left {
      grid-column: 1/2;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .left:before {
    content: "<";
    visibility: visible;
    width: 50px;
    }

    .right {
      grid-column: 2/3;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .right:before {
    content: "<";
    visibility: visible;
    width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <a class="left" href="#"> Left </a>
      <a class="right" href="#"> Right </a>
    </div>
```

How can I make the .right to the right side of the grid?
So like this. I cannot use `text-align: right;` on the `:before` elements as that does not do anything.

[image]

Comment: test-align: right ?

Comment: That sadly doesn't work. I did edit the snippet to show it actually looks. The text is hidden and replaced by '<' on a :before element

Answer (score 1):

Use after for the right arrow:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.left:before {
  content: "<";
  visibility: visible;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align:right;
}

.right:after {
  content: ">";
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="left" href="#"> Left </a>
  <a class="right" href="#"> Right </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `text-align: right;`

```css
div {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
  width: 300px;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="left" href="#"> Left </a>
  <a class="right" href="#"> Right </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I forgot to add on this, the text is actually hidden and there is an :before element on the text (containing a > and < for a slider) so text-align: right; doesn't work sadly

Answer (score -1):

Consider using Flexbox and then align-self :)

Also Very Easy to understand the logic:
https://flexboxfroggy.com/